# creating a vertical CAEmitterLayer

Tags: swift, caemitterlayer, caemittercell

I'm working on creating a CAEmitterLayer that's the height of the screen, and pushed off -X, so the CAEmitterCells travel from left (off the screen) to upper right.

There's an issue I am running into where the emitterSize *height* property of CAEmitterLayer is being ignored. This is causing all the cells to emit from a single point, and not what's set with emitterSize.

Here's the emitter:

```
emitter.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: -50, y: (view.frame.height / 2))
emitter.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerLine
emitter.emitterSize = CGSize(width: 2, height: view.frame.height)
```

i mentioned emitterSize *height* is not working, because if i change the width of the above emitterSize, I can see the width changing properly! No matter what value I put for height... it gets ignored.

And the CAEmitterCells

```
cell.birthRate = 10
cell.lifetime = 10
cell.velocity = CGFloat(50)
cell.emissionLongitude = (45 * (.pi/180))
```

**How can I set the emitterSize width to be 2 points wide and the height of the view?**

Answer (score 3):

`kCAEmitterLayerLine` is always a horizontal line of zero thickness. Only `emitterSize.width` is used.

You can use the line shape vertically by setting your emitter layer's transform to a rotation. Playground example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class VerticalEmitterView: UIView {

    let emitter = CAEmitterLayer()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let bounds = self.bounds
        emitter.position = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        emitter.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.size.height, height: bounds.size.width)
        emitter.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2, y: -50)
        emitter.emitterSize = CGSize(width: emitter.bounds.size.width, height: 0)

        if emitter.superlayer != self.layer {
            emitter.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -.pi / 2))
            emitter.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerLine

            let cell = CAEmitterCell()
            cell.birthRate = 100
            cell.lifetime = 10
            cell.velocity = 50
            cell.emissionLongitude = .pi
            cell.color = UIColor.red.cgColor
            let particleSize = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
            let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: particleSize).image(actions: { (rc) in
                UIColor.white.setFill()
                let gc = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
                UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: particleSize)).fill()
            })
            cell.contents = image.cgImage
            emitter.emitterCells = [cell]

            layer.addSublayer(emitter)
        }
    }

}

let rootView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
rootView.backgroundColor = .white
let emitterView = VerticalEmitterView(frame: rootView.bounds)
rootView.addSubview(emitterView)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = rootView
```

Result:

[image: emitter demo]

(The discontinuity is because this GIF is a one-second loop.)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Looking through Apple's documentation, it looks like if the emitter shape is kCAEmitterLayerLine, it ignores the height of the emitter.

The not-ideal workaround I found was to use a kcaEmitterLayerRectangle with a large enough height so that one side of the rectangle is where you wanted the line to be.

Comment: Wouldn't `kCAEmitterLayerRectangle` be a better choice?

Comment: That does indeed work. But like @jrturton mentioned, you're better off using a rectangle instead of circle.

Comment: @jrturton Yep! The rectangle wasn't working at first for me, but when working correctly, yes it is better than a circle. Edited the answer to include that.